# Test waiting for ng-if element to appear not working

Tags: angularjs, promise, protractor

I am using Protractor. Theres this test im writing: I am waiting for an element to appear. When it appears i'd like to click it. So i've done this:

```
it("Test", () => {
            let k: p.ElementFinder = element(by.className("gift-back"));
            browser.wait(() => {
                let promise = k.isPresent().then((isPresent: boolean) => {
                    console.log(isPresent);
                    return isPresent;
                });
                return promise;
            });
            k.click();
```

The problem is that, the element i am waiting for to appear (the element with class gift-back) is an ng-if element.So this element is not in the DOM all the time and this test is not actually working. Help or warkaround is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in Expected Condition for the ["presence" checks](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf), try it:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.className("gift-back"));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 5000);  // wait up to 5 seconds
```

Comment: ExpectedConditions does not exist... :(

Comment: @Bakanomercy interesting. What protractor version are you using?

Comment: THe version is 3.0.0

Comment: @Bakanomercy strange, expected conditions definitely should be there if it is 3.0.0..recheck if you are really using 3.0.0 please.

Comment: protractor: 3.0.0 - thats in dependencies in the package.json

Comment: i tried the ExpectedConditions. Not working. What happens when i  run the test stated in the question, is that the console.log outputs false all the time. When the element appears, the console.log outputs true. But then the test fails stating that k.click() can not work because the element with class gift-back is not found. Any idea?